# Remove specified number of characters from a string

Tags: c, strings

From an exercise in Kochan's *Programming in C*, following a chapter on C's null-terminated strings:

> Write a function called removeString to remove a specified number of
>   characters from a character string. The function should take three
>   arguments: the source string, the starting index number in the source
>   string, and the number of characters to remove. So, if the character
>   array text contains the string "the wrong son", the call
>
> `removeString (text, 4, 6);`
>
> has the effect of removing the characters “wrong “ (the
>   word “wrong” plus the space that follows) from the array text. The
>   resulting string inside text is then "the son".

I found the exercise interesting to implement. I know I could have used `strlen` to get the length of the string, but I like the idea of handling everything in a single pass (I imagine `strlen` has to traverse the characters looking for a null-byte).

Any comments/criticisms are welcome. Here's my solution:

```
void removeString (char text[], int index, int rm_length)
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < index; ++i )
        if ( text[i] == '\0' )
            return;

    for ( ; i < index + rm_length; ++i )
        if ( text[i] == '\0' ) {
            text[index] = '\0';
            return;
        }

    do {
        text[i - rm_length] = text[i];
    } while ( text[i++] != '\0' );
}
```

And a test drive

```
int main (void)
{
    char string1[] = "the wrong son";
    char string2[] = "the wrong son";
    char string3[] = "the wrong son";

    printf ("string1: %s\n", string1);
    printf ("string2: %s\n", string2);
    printf ("string3: %s\n\n", string3);

    printf ("removeString (string1, 13, 6)\n");
    removeString (string1, 13, 6);
    printf ("string1: %s\n\n", string1);

    printf ("removeString (string2, 11, 6)\n");
    removeString (string2, 11, 6);
    printf ("string2: %s\n\n", string2);

    printf ("removeString (string3, 4, 6)\n");
    removeString (string3, 4, 6);
    printf ("string3: %s\n\n", string3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
string1: the wrong son
string2: the wrong son
string3: the wrong son

removeString (string1, 13, 6)
string1: the wrong son

removeString (string2, 11, 6)
string2: the wrong s

removeString (string3, 4, 6)
string3: the son
```

Comment: Looking at this, curious if `int` is always large enough index for every possible `char[]`. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/secure.html may be of interest.

Comment: Hm, I hadn't considered that. I guess a `long` or `long long` would be better?

Answer (score 5):

One quick stylistic comment.

**Braces**

```
for ( ; i < index + rm_length; ++i )
    if ( text[i] == '\0' ) {
        text[index] = '\0';
        return;
    }
```

Constructs like this are begging to have a subtle hidden bug in them. Always use braces if you have more than a single statement inside a `for`/`if` statement.

```
for (; i < index + rm_length; ++i) {
    if ( text[i] == '\0' ) {
        text[index] = '\0';
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Two loops looking for the same thing: the null character within `n` characters.  They just react differently.  Confident with pipelines architectures, this will be faster.  So instead of 2 loops, use

   ```
   rm_end = index + rm_length;
   for ( i = 0; i < rm_end; ++i ) {
     if ( text[i] == '\0' ) {
       if (i > index) {
         text[index] = '\0';
       }
       return;
     }
   }
   ```
2. In C, *strings* are arrays and array sizes are best indexed with `size_t`, rather than `int`, `long` or `long long`.  `size_t` is the return type of `sizeof`, so `size_t` is neither too small nor excessively wide to represent all possible string sizes.  `int` may be too narrow.  Note: `strlen()` returns type `size_t`.  `size_t` is some unsigned type.
3. C string functions typically return something.  Returning the destination string could be useful with minimal cost.

Putting this all together:

```
char *removeString(char *text, size_t index, size_t rm_length) {
  size_t rm_end = index + rm_length;
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < rm_end; i++) {
    if (text[i] == '\0') {
      if (i > index) {
        text[index] = '\0';
      }
      return text;
    }
  }

  do {
    text[i - rm_length] = text[i];
  } while (text[i++] != '\0');

  return text;
}
```

Pedantic code ensures no addition overflow as in `index + rm_length`:

```
char *removeString(char *text, size_t index, size_t rm_length) {
  if (index >= SIZE_MAX - rm_length) {
    rm_length = SIZE_MAX - 1 - index;
  }

  size_t rm_end = index + rm_length;
  size_t i;
  ...
```

Comment: Why will it be faster to run n + m iterations in a single loop than to run a loop of n iterations followed by a loop of m iterations? Is there that much overhead in setting up each loop?

Comment: @ivan Certainly not a huge difference - it is the same O().  The benefit is platform dependent.  But, _in general_, one short loop, is faster (or as fast) as 2 short loops.

Comment: Interesting, I'm seeing the opposite on my system, except with input that truncates a very short string to an even shorter one. Not a significant difference either way though. Anyway, good to know! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is reasonable but I would prefer it if you used standard library functions instead of rolling your own loops.  And as others have said, use of `size_t` is normal, as is returning a value - the start of the string makes sense in this case.

```
char* removeString (char s[], size_t offset, size_t length)
{
    if (memchr(s, '\0', offset)) {
        return s;
    }
    char *dest = s + offset;
    if (memchr(dest, '\0', length)) {
        *dest = '\0';
        return dest;
    }
    /* Fixed error pointed out by JS1 */
    for (const char *src = dest + length; *dest != '\0'; ++dest, ++src) {
        *dest = *src;
    }        
    return s;
}
```

You could use `memmove` (not `memcpy`, which doesn't handle overlapping areas) in place of the final loop, but that would mean computing the length first.

Comment: Nice, novel use of `memchr()` +1.  Its tempting to profile this, [mine](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/116172/29485), and one that combines the first 2 loops (use 1 memchar()` loop).

Comment: Your copy loop is wrong because is it checking the wrong `dest` character (because it has already advanced by one).  It happens to work because it will stop after reaching the *next* null character, but by that time, `src` will have read past the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code can be more concise if you use memcpy. Based on already provided feedback, I have used `long` instead of `int` and done some checks:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

void removeString (char text[], long index, long rm_length)
{
    long len = strlen(text);
    if (index < 0 || rm_length < 0 || index + rm_length >= len)
        return;

    memmove(&text[index], &text[index + rm_length], len - index - rm_length);
    text[len - rm_length] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char text1[] = "the wrong son";
    removeString (text1, 4, 6);
    printf(text1); printf("\n");

    char text2[] = "text for incorrect indexes";
    removeString (text1, 100, 2);
    printf(text2); printf("\n");

    char text3[] = "text for negative length";
    removeString (text3, 4, -2);
    printf(text3); printf("\n"); printf("\n");
}
```

This is done in [Cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) and should run without any additions. Performance-wise, [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) is advertised as the fastest memory copy function, but I also use `strlen` which has to go through all the string (more details are provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372315/how-to-implement-strlen-as-fast-as-possible)).

**[later edit]**

As correctly pointed out in a comment, [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) should be used, so I have edited my code to use it instead of `memcpy`.

Comment: `memcpy` doesn't handle overlapping areas

Comment: All the tests reveal the opposite and also how memcpy works is specified [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove).

Comment: As your link says, `memcpy` doesn't handle overlapping areas. You may find that it 'works' in your example with your compiler on your target machine, but it is not the correct function to use.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have updated my code.